Eigenvalue Bounds for Block Matrices
I am given question that needs me to prove a lemma, the lemma is as following:
Given a Symmetrical Block Matrix
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}B &C\\C^T & D\end{bmatrix}$$
prove that:
$$λ_{min}(B)+λ_{max}(B)≥λ_{min}(A)+λ_{max}(A)$$
I have tried Rayleigh Quotient but it was to no avail. I thought of an eigenvector for A
that has its last entry zero and tried to find a relation between the eigenvalues of A
and B
yet I cannot come up with anything. Can anyone prove this lemma?

is there a requirement on B, C, D?

Yes A is symmetrical, I've edited the original post. ty

It is not true. Consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.
